# How to Compare localized strings in C#

Tags: c#, localization

I am doing localization for ASP.NET Web Application, when user enters a localized string "XXXX" and i am comparing that string with a value in my localized resource file.

Example :

```
 if ( txtCalender.Text == Resources.START_NOW)
 {
      //do something
 }
```

But When i do that even when the two strings(localized strings) are equal, it returns false. ie.

```
txtCalender.Text ="இப்போது தொடங்க"
Resources.START_NOW="இப்போது தொடங்க"
```

This is localized for Tamil.

Please help..

Comment: Are they case sensitive?

Comment: What can be localized on a string like `XXX`? Please provide better examples next time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I think its just an example.

Comment: your sample in question returns **true**

Comment: Sample i have put text. It works fine when i run the same code in firefox not in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx) overloads that takes a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) value - this allows you to use the current culture for comparison..

```
if ( txtCalender.Text.Equals(Resources.START_NOW, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
{
     //do something
}
```

Or, if you want case insensitive comparison:

```
if ( txtCalender.Text.Equals(Resources.START_NOW,
                             StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Even i tried String.Compare with all culture info and  StringComparison enums.

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - "doesn't work" is really not very descriptive. Are you _certain_ the strings are identical? Same amount of spaces, white space? Are you sure one doesn't have a carriage return at the end and the other doesn't?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - Also, when you put a breakpoint on that line of code, are you sure that `txtCalender.Text` and `Resources.START_NOW` have the expected values?

Comment: Yes.. it has expected values.. I found the problem and fixed it. Posted the answer down there. Thanks.

Comment: -1, it doesn't work. It was a problem with unicode text. See string Normalize() in C#

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian - All I can say is that with the information you posted (including the pasted in text), there is no way to reach your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and it works. Here is the solution,

it was not working when i tried from Chrome browser and it works with Firefox. Actually when i converted both string to char array,

txtCalender.Text Returns 40 characters and Resource.START_NOW returned 46.  So i have tried to  Normalize the string using Normalize() method

```
if(txtCalender.Text.Normalize() == Resources.START_NOW.Normalize())
```

It was interpreting one character as two different characters when i didn't put normalize method.

it has worked fine. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Good that you posted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare with `InvariantCulture` in `String.Equals` (statis method):

```
String.Equals("XXX", "XXX", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
```

Not sure whether this helps though, could others comment on it? I've never come across your actual error.

Comment: Not sure whether these strings are in the same case. Frankly I'm not even sure whether uppercase/lowercase exists in Tamil at all. However, did you also compare case-insensitively?

Comment: Tamil doesn't have upper case/lower case. It was a problem with unicode character, it was interpreting one character as two different characters. When i normalize it, both was same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `.Equals`

```
if(txt.Calendar.Text.Equals(Resources.START_NOW))
{ //...
```

And if case-insensitive comparison is what you're after (often is) use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as the second argument to the `.Equals` call.

If this isn't working - then can I suggest you breakpoint the line and check the actual value of `Resources.START_NOW` - the only possible reason why this equality comparison would fail is if the two strings really aren't the same.  So my guess is that your culture management isn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Equals` or `String.Compare`.

There is some performance differences between these two. String.Compare is faster than String.Equal because String.Compare is static method and String.Equals is instance method.

String.Equal returns a boolean. String.Compare returns 0 when the strings equal, but if they're different they return a positive or negative number depending on whether the first string is before (less) or after (greater) the second string.  Therefore, use String.Equals when you need to know if they are the same or String.Compare when you need to make a decision based on more than equality.